# Finding explicit formula for this recurrence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

This is the recurrence relation: $a_n=a_{n/2}+1,a_1=3$. I have never done this type of recurrence relation. I have been told, that I need to substitute $n/2$ with something else but I can't come up with it.

Comment: By $a(n/2)$, do you mean $a_{n/2}$? This only defines the sequence $(a_n)$ at indices that are a power of $2$; how is it defined elsewhere? Perhaps you missed a floor function there, ie, is it supposed to be $\large a_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$?

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Thanks for pointing it out, I edited it :)

Comment: It still isn't clear if the $(n/2)$ is supposed to be $\large\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ or not.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas I removed the parentheses, that makes it clear right?

Comment: So, is it supposed to be simply $n/2$? If yes, then the recurrence relation defines the sequence only for indices $n$ that are a power of 2 by $a_{2^k}=a_{2^{k-1}}+1$; defining $b_k:=a_{2^k}$ gives $b_k=b_{k-1}+1$ implying $b_k=k+c$ and the initial value gives $b_0=a_1=c=3$, thus $a_{2^n}=n+3$; this doesn't give you any information on the values of $a_k$ when $k$ is not a power of 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_n=a(n/2)+1,a_1=3 $

let's say $n/2=k  => n=2k$

which means n should be a power of two (because n/2 should be integer again due to $a_{n/2}$). Thus, $n =2^{k}$

$$ a_{2^{k}}=a_{2^{k-1}}+1 $$
$$ a_{2^{k-1}}=a_{2^{k-2}}+1 $$
$$ a_{2^{k-2}}=a_{2^{k-3}}+1 $$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$a_{2}=a_{1}+1$$
$$a_{1}=3$$

Now, if we add both Left-hand side and Right-hand side, we'll get:

$$a_{2^k} = k*1 + 3 $$

Therefore:
$$ a_{n} = log_{2}^{n} + 3 $$

Comment: This solution is based on the assumption that the domain for n is $2^{k}: k \in W$.

Comment: Thanks! Everything is clear except the $a_{2^k}=k*1+3$ part.Can you explain how did we get $k*1$ ?

Comment: the concept is similar to this: $x=y+2$ and $y=z+3$ and $z=2$. So, if you add the left hand sides together and put it equal to the summation of right hand side, you will get: $x+y+z = y+2+z+3+2 $ , and it results in $x=7$. (y and z will be cancelled out). Same thing is true for the recursive. The goal is to create sequences of equations  where you can cancel out terms. Each $a_{2^{i}}$ on left will be cancelled by its similar term that is sitting on the right side of its previous equation. So, at the end, what is left is $a_{2^{k}}$ and a bunch of 1 and 3.

Comment: $a_{2}$ is actually $a_{2^k}$ where k=1. So, from this line to a_{2^{k}}, there are k lines and thus you have "k" number of ones that are going to be added together.